# Put Tablet in AndroidManifest

Tags: android, delphi-xe5

how to create a AndroidManifest.template app to be compatible with my tablet. In production works well on my tablet, but when sending to Play store does not appear in the list of tablets. In XE5 has no where to set

Regards

Comment: Does this platform have `AndroidManifest.xml` file in the project package?

Answer (score 1):

You can edit the `AndroidManifest.xml` file for your project, and add the `supports-screens` element:

```
 <supports-screens
      android:largeScreens="true"
      android:normalScreens="true"
      android:smallScreens="true"
      android:anyDensity="true"/>
```

You can open the file by using `File->Open` from the IDE main menu and navigating to your project's folder.

Comment: Thank you. I did that but I get the following message in the store:

Your APK production must meet the following criteria: The recommended and minimum versions are compatible with Android tablets (and check targetSdkVersion minSdkVersion). learn more Any hardware resources required are usually available in tablets.

Regards

Comment: So are you *reading* the message? It tells you clearly that you have to set the minSDKversion and include the proper resources for your target platform. I think you need to spend some time with the Android documentation (available on-line) to learn a little more about Android. :-)

Comment: You should not edit the AndroidManifest.xml file but rather the AndroidManifest.template.xml. When you deploy your project Delphi uses the template and makes the AndroidManifest.xml from that. So it saves over the normal AndroidManifest and you will lose the things you edited!